# Is the Sentence "More importantly, as being a GeorgeTown student, I always have the will to " Structurally Correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, sentence-meaning

English is my second language and I am trying to learn from your expertise.

Is the following sentence grammatically and structurally correct? Is it meaningful? If not, how could I correct it or make it properly meaningful?

> More importantly, as being a GeorgeTown student, I always have the will to ...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***"As a"*** and ***"Being"*** have the same meaning in this context.

> As a Georgetown student...
>
> Being a Georgetown student...

If you wanted to be continuous, you could amend this to ***"While being a"***

> More importantly, while being a Georgetown student...

Capitalization of George and Town implies they are two separate words. If you are referring to the University located in DC then it is *Georgetown*.

Answer (score 0):

More importantly, as being a Georgetown student . . .

should read:

More importantly, **being** a Georgetown student . . .

An alternative way of saying this is:

More importantly, **as** a Georgetown student . . .

Don't try to combine both structures! :-)